# Unlink wall and e.t.c. from Archimesh

Tags: mesh, objects, archimesh-add-on

I created the wall with the **Archimesh** plugin, then I want to disconnect it and edit it like any other object manually.

How can I do it?

---

I will try to explain, although it is difficult in English.
It is necessary to “free” the wall from the plug-in so that it can no longer change it by accidentally clicking on the parameters of length, height, etc.
I created 2 walls, and extruded inserting one of them manually. If I accidentally click on panel right on walls height, length, count e.t.c. my manually editing will be destroyed. [image]
How to avoid it

Comment: It should be its own object, do you mean it's attached to other Archimesh objects? Is it parented to anything in the outliner?

Comment: @SilverWolf, I extended my question.

Comment: I didn't know Archimesh even had that panel, neat!

Comment: In fact its a **Custom Property** so to remove it You need a python scripting I belive. Dunno if the "answer" below is of some help but I want to suggest the same ... sadly I think You mean when U change it by accident without realising it right? Then UNDO is not a solution... Check this: https://blenderartists.org/t/removing-custom-properties-from-objects/567885

Comment: @SilverWolf, I to didn't know Archimesh even had that panel. I create this manually. By Insert (I key) and Extrude (E key) commands.
That's the question, I don't want the plug-in to be able to walt more on the wall

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know how to unlink it from the Archimesh tools. But it is worth noting that if you make a change by accident, **undoing the change** will get you back your custom modifications.

Comment: Imo it was meant as an accidental change without knowing it.